# Parse email by RegExp in JavaScript in one line; make right case insensitive but keep left

Tags: javascript, regex

1. From my code:

   ```
   //yagh ... apparently there's an off-chance email is case sensitive ...

   console.log('yooooooooo0 ' + name.substr(name.indexOf('@')+1));
   //console.log('yooooooooo1 ' + name.substr(name.indexOf('@')+1).toLowercase());
   console.log('yooooooooo1 ' + name.substr(name.indexOf('@')+1).toLowerCase());
   console.log('yooooooooo2 ' + name.substr(name.indexOf('@'),0));
   console.log('yooooooooo3 ' + name.split('@')[0]);
   console.log('yooooooooo4 ' + /[^@]*/.exec(name)[0]);//hmmm mh
   console.log('yooooooooo4_2 ' + /[^@]*$/.exec(name)[0]);//hmmm mh
   //hm yea okay ya
   console.log(name);//nondestructive and
   //pff ...
   console.log((/[^@]*/.exec(name)[0])+'@'+(/[^@]*$/.exec(name)[0]).toLowerCase);
   let tmp = (/[^@]*/.exec(name)[0])+'@'+ (/[^@]*$/.exec(name)[0]).toLowerCase;
   console.log(tmp);
   console.log((/[^@]*/.exec(name)[0])+'@'+name.substr(name.indexOf('@')+1).toLowerCase());
       var pass = $('#pass1').val();

       var crypto = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;

   if(crypto.subtle)
   {
   ```
2. Say the email that comes with is `a@b.C`. The point is, I just found that email is only case insensitive right of the `@`. In theory, admins can choose to let that slide, but in practice most won't to prevent confusion (is what I read).

   I want:

   ```
   console.log((/[^@]*/.exec(name)[0])+'@'+(/[^@]*$/.exec(name)[0]).toLowerCase);
   ```

   I have a working bit that is:

   ```
   console.log((/[^@]*/.exec(name)[0])+'@'+name.substr(name.indexOf('@')+1).toLowerCase());
   ```

   The first one gives me:

   ```
   a@function toLowerCase(){
      [native code]
   }
   ```

   And the second:

   ```
   a@b.c
   ```

   Which is fine, but the first one is prettier and less readable, which is great since no one else will be on it, ever.

   Is there some way to make the first one work? (Assigning it to `let tmp=` gives the same reply when log (`tmp`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```js
console.log((/[^@]*/.exec(name)[0])+'@'+(/[^@]*$/.exec(name)[0]).toLowerCase);
```

by

```js
console.log((/[^@]*/.exec(name)[0])+'@'+(/[^@]*$/.exec(name)[0]).toLowerCase());
```

You could also do this

```
const email = 'some.name@some_domain.com'
const [name, domain] = email.split('@')
console.log(`${name}@${domain}`);
```

Comment: chosen answer as solution ? i'm probably missing the button somewhere.
Ofc. <b>thanks!</b> ... thats why im the hobbyist , brackets, ofcourse and thanks for the extra that looks like shell scriping almost. Oh, checkmark, ofc, yes thanks!!!!